# Suppose that $x,y,z$ are elements of a group and are conjugate. Prove for $H,N \vartriangleleft G$ and $x \in H$ and $y \in N$ that $z\in H\cap N$.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $x,y,z$ are elements of a group and are conjugate.  Prove for $H,N$ normal subgroups of $G$ and $x \in H$ and $y \in N$ that $z\in H\cap N$.

I know and can prove that $H\cap N \vartriangleleft G$ and also that the definition of conjugate is that $\exists g \in G$ s.t. $gxg^{-1}=y$.

But I have tried and cannot get to the end, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If $y\in N$ and $z$ are conjugate then there exists $g \in G$ such that $gyg^{-1}=z$. And so by normality of $N$ we have $z \in N$. You can show in same way that  $z$ is also in $H$ and thus it's in the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\exists g,g'$ such that $gxg^{-1}=y,$ $g'yg'^{-1}=z$;

So $gg'xg'^{-1}g^{-1}=(gg')x(gg')^{-1}=z$;

But now since $z=g'yg'^{-1}$ and $y\in N$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup then $z\in N$

(in fact  $N$ normal subgroup means $N$ closed under conjugations, and so if $y\in N$ then also $g'yg'^{-1}\in N$);

but we know that $(gg')x(gg')^{-1}=z$ and as before since $x\in H$ and $H$ is normal we get $z\in H$ and finally we have $z\in H\cap N$.